# Improve Oracle query for applying monthly factors to a query of monthly budget values

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a brute force way to achieve what I am after but there is probably a more efficient way

```
SELECT sum(jan/(SELECT JAN FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_JAN,  
       sum(feb/(SELECT FEB FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_FEB,  
       sum(mar/(SELECT MAR FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_MAR,  
       sum(apr/(SELECT APR FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_APR,  
       sum(may/(SELECT MAY FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_MAY,  
       sum(jun/(SELECT JUN FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_JUN,  
       sum(jul/(SELECT JUL FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_JUL,  
       sum(aug/(SELECT AUG FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_AUG,  
       sum(sep/(SELECT SEP FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_SEP,  
       sum(oct/(SELECT OCT FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_OCT,  
       sum(nov/(SELECT NOV FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_NOV,  
       sum(dec/(SELECT DEC FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')) as FACTORED_DEC,  
       sum( 
                jan/(SELECT JAN FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                feb/(SELECT FEB FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                mar/(SELECT MAR FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                apr/(SELECT APR FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                may/(SELECT MAY FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                jun/(SELECT JUN FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                jul/(SELECT JUL FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                aug/(SELECT AUG FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                sep/(SELECT SEP FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                oct/(SELECT OCT FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                nov/(SELECT NOV FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017') + 
                dec/(SELECT DEC FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS WHERE YEAR = '2017')  
                ) as FACTORED_YEAR_TOTAL 
                FROM MONTHLY_BUDGET  
                WHERE DEPT = '123ABC' AND YEAR = '2017'
```

The MONTHLY_FACTORS table looks like

```
YEAR JAN FEB ... DEC
2016   3   2 ...   4
2017 ...
```

The MONTHLY_BUDGET table looks like

```
YEAR DEPT    JAN     FEB   ...  DEC
2016 123abc  50234   20032      22234
2017 123abc  ...
2016 xyz456  40054   23002 ...  44442
```

The EXPECTED OUTPUT looks like

```
YEAR    JAN/JAN_FACTOR     FEB/FEB_FACTOR   ...  DEC/DEC_FACTOR
```

Is there a cleaner way without all the sub queries?

Comment: Would be helpful to see an example of the expected output.  I do not see a column named DEPT in your sample data for the MONTHLY_BUDGET table.

Comment: I should have not muddied the waters with the dept number.  I should have left it out.

Comment: Is the table format fixed or could it be changed to be year and month on single rows?

Comment: table structure is set and can not be changed.  I don't own them.

Comment: 'select * from MONTHLY_FACTORS where year= '2017' ' and 'select * from MONTHLY_BUDGET where DEPT = '123ABC' AND YEAR = '2017' '=> do each statement  return one row?

Comment: Are you allowed to use views?

Comment: @mehmetsahin yes each query returns 1 row

Comment: @Stilgar  I am using these queries within a Java EE application and utilizing JPA.  Right now I am working on just doing two separate queries and then using Java to modify the values.  I was hoping to do the division within the query.  I don't want to use views

Comment: Sorry, my bad, missed the part where you said you were calling this from Java.  Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Formatted on 8/2/2017 11:07:39 PM (QP5 v5.287) */
WITH a
     AS (  SELECT year,
                  SUM (jan) jan,
                  SUM (feb) feb,
                  SUM (mar) mar,
                  SUM (apr) apr,
                  SUM (may) may,
                  SUM (jun) jun,
                  SUM (jul) jul,
                  SUM (aug) aug,
                  SUM (sep) sep,
                  SUM (oct) oct,
                  SUM (nov) nov,
                  SUM (dec) dec
             FROM MONTHLY_BUDGET
            WHERE DEPT = '123abc' and year= 2017
         GROUP BY dept, year),
     b
     AS (SELECT JAN,
                FEB,
                MAR,
                APR,
                MAY,
                JUN,
                JUL,
                AUG,
                SEP,
                OCT,
                NOV,
                DEC,
                year
           FROM MONTHLY_FACTORS where year = 2017)
SELECT a.jan / b.JAN,
       a.feb / b.FEB,
       a.mar / b.mar,
       a.apr / b.apr,
       a.may / b.may,
       a.jun / b.jun,
       a.jul / b.jul,
       a.aug / b.aug,
       a.sep / b.sep,
       a.oct / b.oct,
       a.nov / b.nov,
       a.dec / b.dec
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.year = b.year
```

The above query not a good solution but more simple.

Note: It is not important 'select * from MONTHLY_BUDGET where DEPT = '123ABC' AND YEAR = '2017' statement returns one or more rows. If you guarantee it return one row dont use 'sum' in 'with a' clause.

On the other hand, we can write a function for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by unpivoting the tables so you have year/month rows.  Views would work for that.  If you can add views to the database, great.  If not, you can convert these to inline views.

I used M01 for Jan, M02 for Feb.  But those are just labels and you can use whatever you want.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tmp_MF
AS
WITH
     MF AS
        (
        SELECT
             TO_CHAR(Year)      AS Year
            ,TO_CHAR(M01)       AS M01
            ,TO_CHAR(M02)       AS M02
            ,TO_CHAR(M03)       AS M03
            ,TO_CHAR(M04)       AS M04
            ,TO_CHAR(M05)       AS M05
            ,TO_CHAR(M06)       AS M06
            ,TO_CHAR(M07)       AS M07
            ,TO_CHAR(M08)       AS M08
            ,TO_CHAR(M09)       AS M09
            ,TO_CHAR(M10)       AS M10
            ,TO_CHAR(M11)       AS M11
            ,TO_CHAR(M12)       AS M12
        FROM tmp_Monthly_Factors                mf
        )
SELECT
     Year
    ,"Value"
    ,"Month"
FROM mf
UNPIVOT
    (
    "Value"
    FOR "Month" IN (M01,M02,M03,M04,M05,M06,M07,M08,M09,M10,M11,M12)
    )
;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tmp_MB
AS
    WITH
     MB AS
        (
        SELECT
             TO_CHAR(mb.Year)       AS Year
            ,Dept
            ,TO_CHAR(M01)       AS M01
            ,TO_CHAR(M02)       AS M02
            ,TO_CHAR(M03)       AS M03
            ,TO_CHAR(M04)       AS M04
            ,TO_CHAR(M05)       AS M05
            ,TO_CHAR(M06)       AS M06
            ,TO_CHAR(M07)       AS M07
            ,TO_CHAR(M08)       AS M08
            ,TO_CHAR(M09)       AS M09
            ,TO_CHAR(M10)       AS M10
            ,TO_CHAR(M11)       AS M11
            ,TO_CHAR(M12)       AS M12
        FROM tmp_Monthly_Budget             mb
        )
SELECT
     Year
    ,Dept
    ,"Month"
    ,"Value"
FROM mb
UNPIVOT
    (
    "Value"
    FOR "Month" IN (M01,M02,M03,M04,M05,M06,M07,M08,M09,M10,M11,M12)
    )
;
```

Then I think a PIVOT query will get you the desired result.  This might need a little tweaking but should be close:

```
    WITH 
     Pivot_Data AS
        (
        SELECT
             tmp_MB.Year
            ,tmp_MB.Dept
            ,tmp_MB."Month"
    --      ,tmp_MB."Value" AS Budget_Value
    --      ,tmp_MF."Value" AS Monthly_Factor
            ,ROUND(tmp_MB."Value" / tmp_MF."Value",2) AS Month_Value
        FROM tmp_MB
            --
            JOIN tmp_MF
                ON  tmp_MF.Year   = tmp_MB.Year
                AND tmp_MF."Month" = tmp_MB."Month"
        WHERE (1 = 1)
    --    AND tmp_MB.Year = 2016
        )
SELECT
     Year
    ,Dept
    ,"Jan"  AS "Factored Jan"
    ,"Feb"
    ,"Mar"
    ,"Apr"
    ,"May"
    ,"Jun"
    ,"Jul"
    ,"Aug"
    ,"Sep"
    ,"Oct"
    ,"Nov"
    ,"Dec"
    ,"Jan" + "Feb" + "Mar" + "Apr" + "May" + "Jun" + "Jul" + "Aug" + "Sep" + "Oct" + "Nov" + "Dec" AS "Factored Year Total"
FROM Pivot_Data
PIVOT
    (
    MAX(Month_Value) FOR "Month" IN
        (
         'M01'      AS "Jan"
        ,'M02'      AS "Feb"
        ,'M03'      AS "Mar"
        ,'M04'      AS "Apr"
        ,'M05'      AS "May"
        ,'M06'      AS "Jun"
        ,'M07'      AS "Jul"
        ,'M08'      AS "Aug"
        ,'M09'      AS "Sep"
        ,'M10'      AS "Oct"
        ,'M11'      AS "Nov"
        ,'M12'      AS "Dec"
        )
    )
ORDER BY Year, Dept
;
```